# Read from and write to file from stdin and stdout

Tags: bash, files, stdout, stdin

I need to continually read from and write to a (virtual) file in bash, *without closing the file in between*. I'm looking for a program which will open the file for read and write, read from stdin and write what it reads to the file AND read from the file and write it to stdout. A bit like `netcat` but for files.

The file in question is a virtual file in /sys (a custom thing in something I'm working on) to which one writes a command and reads to receive the response - where the write and subsequent read must be done in the same session, i.e. on the same file descriptor without closing it in between.

Easy to do in C - `open("file", O_RDWR)`, `write()`, `read()` - note: no need to `seek()`.

Is there a standard GNU tool or do I need to write one?

Comment: Maybe you can used tee to achieve what you need? It will not *read* from the file though, but will copy to stdout what it writes to the file.

Comment: If the suggestions that you've gotten so far aren't satisfactory to you, try explaining what you want to do a bit more clearly.  For example, are you starting with an empty file (or maybe a non-existent file), reading from stdin, and writing the data to both the file and stdout?  Or is there something already in the file when you start?  If so, do you want the new data to overwrite the old data?  In this case, do you want data from stdin to end up on stdout (after being written to the file), or do you want only the *original* contents of the file to be written to stdout?

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Is that file behaving like a regular file (seekable, and `read()` return 0 bytes (EOF) when the end is reached), or like a bi-directional pipe or socket (where what you write is not what  you may read again after seeking and where `read()` blocks when there's no available input)?

Answer (score 4):

The redirection operator to open a file in read+write mode without truncation is `<>` in all Bourne-like shells (that maps to `open(file, O_RDWR|O_CREAT)` (though `zsh` also throws in a `O_NOCTTY`) or `fopen(file, "w+")`):

```
exec 3<> "$file"
```

opens the `$file` on file descriptor 3 in read+write mode (without truncating it and creating it if it didn't exist).

However, only `ksh93` and `zsh` have *seeking* operators. `dd` can seek, but not backwards. And note no shell except `zsh` can have NUL bytes in their variables.

In `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
exec 3<> $file
sysread -i 3 -c 2 var # a read() of 2 bytes
sysseek -u 3 0 # seek back to beginning
# or sysseek -u 3 -w current -2 # to seek back 2 bytes
syswrite -o 3 something-else
exec 3<&- # close
```

In `ksh93`:

```
exec 3<> "$file"
var=$(dd bs=2 count=1 <&3 2>/dev/null; echo .)
var=${var%?}
exec 3<#((0)) # seek to beginning
# or exec 3<#((CUR-2)) # to seek back 2 bytes
print -ru3 something-else
```

Portably, you could still open the file several times, for each offset you want, like here to read and write 2 bytes at offset 2 (provided they're not bytes with value 0 if not using `zsh`):

```
var=$(dd bs=2 count=1 skip=1 < "$file"; echo .)
var=${var%?}
printf %s something-else | dd bs=2 seek=1 1<> "$file"
```

Or:

```
printf %s something-else | dd bs=2 seek=1 of="$file" conv=notrunc
```

To read and write to the same file, `ksh93` has two other interesting redirection operators:

```
tr 01 10 < file >; file
```

Would store the output of `tr` in a temporary file and if `tr` is successful, rename that to `file` (beware the file is created anew, so with possibly different permissions and ownership).

```
tr -d 0 < file 1<>; file
```

Same as the standard/Bourne `tr -d 0 < file 1<> file` except that if `tr` succeeds, `file` is truncated where `tr` finished writing. You can use that for filter commands that produce less output than they read input, or more precisely commands that would not read data that they've previously written.

And `zsh` has the `=(...)` form of process substitution which you can use as:

```
 mv =(tr 01 10 < file) file
```

(with similar effect and caveats as `ksh93`'s `>;`). Or:

```
 cp =(tr 01 10 < file) file
```

which would preserve attributes of `file` but means an extra copy.

---

Now if you need to read and write at the same offset using the same file descriptor and neither zsh nor ksh93 are available, you could always revert to `perl`/`python`/`ruby`...

```
perl -e '
  open F, "<>", "file" or die "open: $!";
  read F, $var, 1;
  seek F, 0, 0;
  print F "something-else"'
```

---

Now, after re-reading the updated version of your question, it looks like your file is behaving more like a socket or bidirectional pipe, and not like a regular, seekable file.

In which case, it could be just a matter of:

```
socat - file:your-file
```

or:

```
(cat >&3 3>&- & cat <&3 3<&-) 3<> your-file
```

to feed data from and to that file as read from/to stdin/stdout.

Note that each `cat` reads/writes to its own copy of the file descriptor 3 open by the shell, but they share the same *open file description* so it should be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't open the file several times: the write and read must be on the same file descriptor. I'll have a play with the `exec 3<> /sys/blah` technique and see if I can get anywhere, thanks.

Comment: It's worth to note that `>;` and `<>;` can not be used with `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing translation *only*, you can't read and write at the same time safely (and even with translation, it's possible that the file may end up "half translated" if the program exits with an error).

It sounds like you really want some combination of `tee` and `sponge`. You can use `sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) to soak up standard input and then write it out to a file. You can use `tee` to duplicate input to multiple outputs.

The end result would look something like this:

```
command < filename | tee >(sponge filename)
```

`>()` is an example of [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). In this case, `>(sponge filename)` is replaced with the path to a FIFO that goes to the stdin of `sponge`, which `tee` writes to. `tee` also writes its input to stdout independently.

Here's an example. You can see that the output is both written to stdout, and written to the file.

```
$ echo 'foo bar' > file
$ sed 's/foo/qux/' < file | tee >(sponge file)
qux bar
$ cat file
qux bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited my question to make it more explicit. Firstly, I need to write to the file before reading.  (Before AND after would be OK too.) Secondly the reads and writes need to be done on the same file descriptor.

Comment: How is `command < filename | tee >(sponge filename)` solving the _half translated_ problem?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It doesn't. :-) That why I said "even with translation", not "with translation".

Comment: Note that if `$TMPDIR` is on the same filesystem as `filename`, then `filename` is created anew. While `sponge` will try and reproduce permissions, that will not be the case for other file attributes (ownership, ACLs, extended attributes...).